# TextView not retaining the value I give it

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, view

In my app, I'm getting JSON data from a php script. When I get the data, I have an `onClick()` method in my Fragment which changes a `TextView` to the parsed JSON.

However, when I swipe to a different fragment(it's a swipe/tabbed activity) my `TextView` does not retain the value I gave it, it changes to the original value.

I want it to retain the value.

MainActivity.java (I don't think this is important)

```
package me.anshsehgal.lunchmenu;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String JSON_STRING;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;  //make all the variables

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager); //reference them
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new HomeFragment(),"Mon");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new MondayFragment(),"Tue");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new TuesdayFragment(),"Wed");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new WednesdayFragment(), "Thu");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new ThursdayFragment(), "Fri");   //adding fragments to view page adapter


        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        HomeFragment frag = (HomeFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.homeFragment);

    }
```

HomeFragment.java (this is where things going wrong)

```
package me.anshsehgal.lunchmenu;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.lang.Void;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    String JSON_STRING;
    String  jsonData;
    TextView txt;
    String day;
    String soup;
    String non_veg_main;
    String non_veg_side;
    String veg_main;
    String veg_side;
    String MondayMenu;
    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textJSON);
        Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonGetJSON);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        new BackgroundTask().execute();


        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();


        try{
            //JSON parsing
            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
            JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);

            //JSON data assigning to variables
             day = finalObject.getString("day");
             soup = finalObject.getString("soup");
             non_veg_main = finalObject.getString("non_veg_main");
            non_veg_side = finalObject.getString("non_veg_side");
            veg_main = finalObject.getString("veg_main");
            veg_side = finalObject.getString("veg_side");

        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MondayMenu = "Soup: "+soup+"\n"+"Non Veg Main: "+non_veg_main+"\n"+"Non Veg Side: "+non_veg_side+"\n"+"Veg Main: "+veg_main+"\n"+"Veg Side: "+veg_side;
        txt.setText(MondayMenu);
    }

    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{


            String json_url;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                json_url="http://192.168.0.12/json_get_data.php";
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(json_url);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING + "\n");
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                 jsonData = result;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because getView is being called everytime you switch from a page to the other. So the TextView is being re-created. Create a ViewHolder with that text, set it on the creator of the ViewHolder class, so you won't lose the value when you re-draw the fragment. [Official viewHolder tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

Comment: I don't understand how to implement this in my case, all tutorials have been about ListViews.

Comment: In your fragment, include a inned class named ViewHolder, where you Bind your views and use a String var to save the EditText value.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm lost after creating the ViewHolder class. Can you show me how my code should look like? I'm just starting with Android dev and all this is pretty confusing to me.

Comment: Just try adding a `String myText;` in your fragment.
`onCreateView(){ txt.setText(myText); }` & `myText = MondayMenu` when you get MondayMenu value

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to keep the state of the fragment when you switching between different tabs, you can follow the implementation below:

```
TextView vstup;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.whatever);
    vstup = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.whatever);
    /* (...) */
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
    state.putCharSequence(App.VSTUP, vstup.getText());
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    vstup.setText(state.getCharSequence(App.VSTUP));
}
```

Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: What is the `App` here? I get an error: unable to resolve symbol App        FYI I'm creating these `@Override` methods in my fragment, not activity

Comment: You can treat App.VSTUP as an constant string.